# ¿Cómo obtener el promedio bajo alto de un conjunto de datos numéricos?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
546700  1
123000  2
97000   3
90000   4
85000   5
80000   6
70000   7
69000   8
65000   9
60000   10
49000   11
12000   12
8500    13
5600    14
```

```sql
select top 5 avg(salary) from Employee
```

Con esta consulta obtendría el promedio de los 5 mas altos.

¿Como obtengo el promedio de los 5 mas bajos?

Answer (score 7):

**No**, con esa consulta no obtienes el promedio de los 5 salarios más altos, porque:

1.- La función `AVG` se ejecuta antes del `TOP`, lo que tu estas haciendo es obtener el promedio de TODA la tabla. Prueba con `TOP 1`, `TOP 2`, `TOP 3`, `TOP 4`, etc y verás que siempre es el mismo resultado

2.- No usas `ORDER BY`, por lo que no te aseguras que siempre sean los salarios más altos. El orden de una consulta SIN order by no está asegurado y puede variar al realizar exactamente la misma consulta.

Esta consulta devuelve el promedio de los 5 salarios más altos

```
SELECT AVG(R.salary) from
(
 SELECT TOP 5 salary
 FROM Employee
 order by salary desc
) as R
```

Y para los más bajos, solo hay que cambiar el orden (de `desc` a `asc`)

```
SELECT AVG(R.salary) from
(
 SELECT TOP 5 salary
 FROM Employee
 order by salary asc
) as R
```